# Evaluate the definite integral using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

I've calculated the following definite integral, and would like to know if my calculation appears to be correct:

$$\int_2^3{\frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x}}}\,\,dx = \int_2^3{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1)}}\,\,dx$$

Using substitution:

$$u = \sqrt{x}-1,\,\, \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-0,\,\, du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$

So

$$2\int{\frac{1}{u}}\,\,du = 2\ln{|u|}+c = 2\ln{|\sqrt{x}-1|}+c$$

Evaluating the integral, we get

$$2\ln{(\sqrt{3}-1)} - 2\ln{(\sqrt{2}-1)} = 2\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\right)$$

Which, if calculated, comes out to approx. $1.1389$.

I'd appreciate any feedback, in case I may have overlooked something in my calculation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You did it exactly right. One of the best ways to confirm that an antiderivative is correct is to differentiate your answer back and see if you get the original integrand. Your solution works out correctly. (The only other check is to make sure that your integral is not considerably undefined in the interval of integration).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback!